# How can I animate the scrollTop function with animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am using a function to store a position where i want the page to reload to when clicked, function works fine but I would like to **animate** the scroll.

```
;(function($){

/**
 * Store scroll position for and set it after reload
 *
 * @return {boolean} [loacalStorage is available]
 */
$.fn.scrollPosReload = function(){
    if (localStorage) {
        var posReader = localStorage["posStorage"];
        if (posReader) {
            $(window).scrollTop(posReader);
            localStorage.removeItem("posStorage");
        }
        $(this).click(function(e) {
            localStorage["posStorage"] = $(window).scrollTop();
        });

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/* ================================================== */

$(document).ready(function() {
    // Trigger the reload
    $('#edit').scrollPosReload();
});

}(jQuery));
```

Any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `animate()` a `scrollTop` property. The only problem is that `window` object doesn't have a `scrollTop` property, only element nodes have it. The jQuery `scrollTop()` method has extra implementation to work on `window` and `document`.

So, in order to scroll the page in animated manner, usually this code is used

```
$('html, body').animate({scrollTop: posReader});
```

(The selector contains both `html` and `body` elements due to some browser inconsistencies (didn't check if the issue still exists)).

Also, the `localStorage` stores and retrieves data as strings, so it's a good idea to cast the read value to number, although **often** it won't make a difference for jQuery.

Full code:

```
;(function($) {

  /**
   * Store scroll position for and set it after reload
   *
   * @return {boolean} [loacalStorage is available]
   */
  $.fn.scrollPosReload = function() {
    if (window.localStorage) {
      var posReader = localStorage["posStorage"];

      if (posReader) {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: +posReader
        });
        localStorage.removeItem("posStorage");
      }

      $(this).click(function(e) {
        localStorage["posStorage"] = $(window).scrollTop();
      });

      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

  /* ================================================== */

  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Trigger the reload
    $('#edit').scrollPosReload();
  });

}(jQuery));
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/rafael/cvwptd1h/1/)

Comment: Sorry this actually doesn't work - cleared my caches and how I put the code with the answer above fails to scroll at all. This is how I changed the code with the above answer - https://gist.github.com/neilgee/a36d3e7772726ee397ec8e1199062154

Comment: @neilgee you used the `animate` in wrong place. Please see my updated answer